# Is there any easier way to replace all the fonts that are set into the xib in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, replace, fonts, xib

I want to replace a font family in xcode, what is the easier way to do it, one way is to go to every xib file and set the font again
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by opening the xib file as "Open as source code"

[image: xcode]

Now use Find and Replace [CMD + ALT + SHIFT + F] and replace the current font family with your font family.

[image: FindAndReplace]

You can do this for all of your storyboards or xib files

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked, but have to do for many storyboards. But was quick as compared to manually changing inside a xib file

Answer (score 6):

Using the terminal, go to the project directory and run this command to replace all strings in the project with any new string:

**Use it carefully, save changes before executing this:**

```
LC_ALL=C find . -type f -name '*.xib' -exec sed -i '' 's/OLD_TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/NEW_TEXT/' {} +
```

example:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -type f -name '*.xib' -exec sed -i '' 's/name="AvenirNext-Regular" family="Avenir Next"/name="Gibson-Regular" family="Gibson"/' {} +
```

Comment: Thanks you save the day, this is an easy way to replace the font in all stories. Thanks!

Comment: This saved me SO much time